# How to write sub quires in Criteria API?

Tags: hibernate

I am working with Hibernate ,I have a table data like below

```
 ---SID---SNAME----CITY_NAME----COURSE_NAME
 ---------------------------------------
    1     BALU       HYD           HTML
    2     HARI       PUNE         .NET
    3     SRAVYA     HYD          JAVA
    4     SOUJI      VIZAG        .NET
    5     UMA        PUNE         JAVA
```

Like I have Data .I want to write query like this
  **select * from student where city-name='hyd' and course_name='java'** .But my problem is 
**I don't have input values like hyd and java** .I have to find the values from Student table(Above table) and do the query.How can I do this by using either HQL or Criteria(My Idea is I want to use sub Quires) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If u have create all the persistent class, done all mapping, created session, then do like this,

```
Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(Student .class);
cr.add(Restrictions.eq("CITY_NAME", "HYD"));
cr.add(Restrictions.eq("COURSE_NAME", "JAVA"));
List results = cr.list();
```

Comment: check this for tutorial http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_criteria_queries.htm